# If $X$ is totally ordered, has the least upper bound property, and has a countable dense subset, then is $X$ isomorphic to an interval of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-numbers, order-theory

Let $X$ be a totally ordered set which has the least upper bound property and has an at most countable dense subset. Assume that $X$ has more than one element. Is $X$ isomorphic to some interval of $\mathbb R$?

Clarifications of terminology:

- $Q\subseteq X$ is **dense** in a totally ordered set $X$ if and only if for all $x,y\in X$ such that $x<y$, there exists $q\in Q$ such that $x<q<y$.
- Totally ordered sets $X$ and $Y$ are **isomorphic** if and only if there exists a monotonically increasing bijection $X\to Y$.
- **Intervals** of $\mathbb R$ are $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $[a,b]$, $(a,\infty)$, $(-\infty,b)$, $[a,\infty)$, $(-\infty,b]$, and $\mathbb R$.

I know that the conclusion is not true when I just assume that $X$ is a linear continuum with more than one element. But I do not know what happens with my stronger assumption.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Connectedness follows from LUB.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Whoops, sorry, I could have sworn that density was an additional property of the ordering as a whole.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Actually, I just noted OP's definition of "dense" doesn't assume $(x,y)\neq \emptyset$, so it actually implies $(x,y)$ is nonempty and then does imply connectedness with LUB.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, you have to add $(x,y) \neq \emptyset$ for $x < y$. Otherwise, each finite set or the Cantor set are counterexamples. With this additional prerequsite, it characterizes intervals, which is well-known in case of $\mathbb R$. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130199/characterizing-sets-which-are-order-isomorphic-to-subsets-of-real-numbers) in case it has no minimum and maximum. From this, the other cases can easily be derived.

Comment: I just noticed that $(x, y) \neq \emptyset$ follows from the requirement that $X$ has a (countable) dense subset. So, yes, the above completely characterizes intervals, indeed. It's just a little bit confusing, since "dense-in-itself" and separability usually formulated separately.